# Git не видит свою папку

Tags: git

После сегодняшнего открытия папки с проектом обнаружил, что гита просто нет как и всех моих веток, хотя папка .git пристуствует, сам git пишет: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. Как это можно исправить не переинициализируя git? В проекте много коммитов, которые мне нужны.

Comment: прям так сложно судить, нужно смотреть, что там именно пропало с папки .git, возможно и можно восстановить. Но лучше понять, почему это произошло, может диск сипется?

Comment: Так спульте с origin ...

Comment: боюсь, что автор не пушил

Comment: @KoVadim, возможно :) У мя стальное правило: завершаешь работу — коммит и пуш; если недоделанная фича, то помечаю аля "intermediate" или просто в отдельную ветку, без разницы, главное, чтобы ушло на сервер.

Comment: Видимо действительно моя главная ошибка, что не пушил. C git работаю недавно, поэтому даже не думал, что такое может произойти. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь